# dom parser is ignoring strong tag

Tags: jquery, html, reactjs, domparser, pdfmake

i want to convert html to text using dom parser.when i used dom parser it is ignoring all the html tags.i need to parse the text which considers all html tags.
i need a text like I am **strong** 
but i'm getting I am strong

```
 handleClick() {
var data = [{Text1:"<strong>Strong text</strong>"}]
            var encodedStr = data[0].Text1
            var parser = new DOMParser();
                    var dom = parser.parseFromString(
                        encodedStr,
                        'text/html');
                        console.log(dom.body.textContent)
                    var decodedString = dom.body.textContent;

                    console.log(decodedString)
                    var docDefinition = { content: [{ text: decodedString, fontSize: 9, alignment: 'justify', margin: [5, 2, 10, 20] },], pageOrientation: 'portrait', pageSize: 'A4' };
                    pdfMake.createPdf(docDefinition).download('optionalName.pdf');

                    console.log(this.decodedString)


                }
```

Comment: You are getting the `textContent`, obviously you won't get the markup. If what you want is the markup then either don't parse your string (oO), or use an XMLSerializer to get an XHTML version, or inner/outerHTML properties of your Element.

Answer (score 0):

Can you try the following method, by changing your docDefinition,

```
var docDefinition = {
  content: [
    { text: decodedString, style: 'header' },
  ],

  styles: {
    header: {
      fontSize: 9,bold: true, alignment: 'justify', margin: [5, 2, 10, 20]
    }
  },
  pageOrientation: 'portrait', 
  pageSize: 'A4' 
};
```

Comment: I guess its because you are parsing out the string and giving the simple text for creating the pdf

Comment: yes,because the pdf make can accept only text so i need to convert to text.if i'm passing the html content it's giving error